# Execution Order Of Overloaded Functions in C#

Tags: c#, execution, overloading

Just wondering how C# determines the order of execution on an object in Method Overload
For instance I have a Method

```
bool SomeMethod(IQueryable source)
{
  //.... Do Work
}

bool SomeMethod(IEnumerable source)
{
   //.... Do Work
}

var Obj = Db.Table.Where(ID > 5);

SomeMethod(Obj);
```

When I run this the code goes to the IQueryable Overload,  Now is that because I declared IQueryable First, is it because IQueryable is of Type IEnumerable or is there some other underlying reason why?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a betterness algorithm (section 7.4.3 of the C# spects) for deciding which method overload to use in the event that there are multiple applicable overloads.  In this case an `IQueryable` is implicitly convertible to an `IEnumerable`, but an `IEnumerable` is not implicitly convertible to an `IQueryable`, making `IQueryable` the "better" overload.

**See Also**
[7.4.2.3 Better conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

.NET compiler is always looking for a **most specific** overload. Suppose you have a simple function that accepts a single parameter, with overloads for object and string parameters. If you are passing a string, string is an object, but string overload is more specific, so it will be called. With complex function signatures and many overloads sometimes you get compiler error "not most specific". See also:

- [Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'method' is most specific for these arguments:error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hx4ayzs(v=vs.90).aspx)